# I want to prevent the plot line from hanging over the axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

As you can see in the attached image, the line of the graph hangs over the axis, how can I make it not hang over the axis?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816589/how-to-hide-the-lines-of-a-graph-in-matlab-so-that-they-do-not-extend-beyond-the

Comment: This problem solved by above question!

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be to call something like

```
ylim([min(y(:))-0.02*range(y(:)) Inf]);
```

after plotting your data `y`. The 2% margin may be adjusted to your tastes.