# How to hide the lines of a graph in MATLAB so that they do not extend beyond the frame

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Is there any way to hide the overflow so that the lines don't protrude from the frame as in the attached image?

```
plot(sin(0:0.1:10),"LineWidth",10)
```

[image]

Comment: maybe a good solution is to expand the graphic bounderies

Comment: As the lines are primitives, they don't really have "area" , so you can not. The only way is extending the axis, just do `axis([-5 105 -1.2 1.2])`

Comment: @Ander but you can ;)

Comment: @Wolfie ah! look at me, being fooled by knowledge! :D Great answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the axes [clipping style](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-ClippingStyle) to `rectangle`

```
plot(sin(0:0.1:10),"LineWidth",10);
set( gca, 'ClippingStyle', 'rectangle' );
```

[image: plot]